# Did the Maccabees properly restore the temple?

Tags: chanuka, beis-hamikdash, book-of-maccabees, mizbeach-altar

In the fourth chapter of [1 Maccabees](https://www.sefaria.org/The_Book_of_Maccabees_I.4?lang=bi) it outlines the steps the Maccabees took to restore the Beit HaMikdash including disassembling the defiled altar (verses 43-46) repairing the utensils, placing the show-bread and dedicating the altar.

I have no reason to assume those verses are in definite chronological order, to me they seem to just be an accounting of all the steps the Maccabees took to restore the temple. I could imagine many other scenarios for how they could have restored the temple; for instance they could have repaired the altar instead, or they could have put up the new altar, had a dedication ceremony and then fixed other things.

My question is, based either on the depiction in 1 Maccabees or any other contemporary source, did the Maccabees restore the Beit HaMikdash in the proper way and in the proper order?

Comment: If it helps point us in the right direction, Middot 1:6 states exactly where the Hashmonaim hid the stones of the defiled altar, while 1 Maccabees 4:45 says they placed the stones in an undisclosed location.